# wordpress plugin redirects instead of performing search

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin; the plugin has item listings, and I want to search for items in the listings.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=listing'); ?>" id="search" >
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder='Search'/>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, the URL redirects to:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?q=shock
```

And no search occurs! How do I fix this?

Comment: Why are you redirecting to the admin page of your WP site? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `page` parameter gets erased.

You are using a `GET` method and `q` parameter overrides all other parameters in a query string, which is `page=listing`.

Two possible solutions:

1. use `POST` by setting `method="post"` attribute, in which case `q` will be passed as a POST parameter to a page with URL `.../admin.php?page=listing`.
2. include the `page` parameter inside your form (`<input type="hidden" name="page" value="listing"/>`) and replace `admin_url('admin.php?page=listing');` with `admin_url('admin.php');`, in which case you'll end up on `.../admin.php?page=listing&q=shock`, because your form will contain both `q` and `page` parameters.

The choice really depends on how your plugin obtains the search string: GET or POST parameter.